# Keyword search of file names in PHP

Tags: php, search, directory, filenames, keyword

With another coder's help, I have PHP code that creates a photo gallery with auto-created thumbnail images of any image files in the directory. (It's open source, so anyone else is free to use and modify as they desire.)

I use it as a stock photo library and the file names include the keywords for that image. For example, one might be **businessman-tie-suit-briefcase-office-meeting.jpg**.

I've been trying to add a keyword search input that looks at the file names, but cannot figure out how to proceed. I've built keyword searches for a database, but this directory file name search is new to me.

Here's the relevant code of the page:

```
    <?
$gallery = $_GET["gallery"];
$dir = $dir.$gallery."/";

//Put files into an array
// create a handler to the directory
$dirhandler = opendir($dir);

// read all the files from directory
$nofiles=0;
while ($file = readdir($dirhandler)) {

    // if $file isn't this directory or its parent 
    //add to the $files array
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
            $nofiles++;
            $files[$nofiles]=$file;                
        }   
    }

//close the handler
closedir($dirhandler);

//Back button to appear at the top of each page to go to the previous directory if not on the main page
if ($gallery !="" or $keyword !="") 
    {
        echo "<div><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'><img src='images/up.png' border='0'></a></div>";
    }

// BEGINNING ADD FOR KEYWORD SEARCH 
// KEYWORD SEARCH BOX- create text box to search entire directory for that keyword and display page in grid pattern with results
?>
    <div style='position:relative; left:10px;'>
        <form action='index_search.php?keyword=$keyword' method='get' name='search'>
            <input type='text' name='keyword' size='25'>
            <input type='submit' value='Search Keyword'>
        </form> 
    </div>

<?  

//*************************************************************************//
// PERFORM KEYWORD SEARCH
if ($keyword !="") 
{
    echo "<div class='keytext'>Keyword search: <b>" . $keyword . "</b><br/></div>";
        /*********************************************************************************************************/

    /* ***** THIS IS WHERE THE SEARCH OF DIRECTORY FILES NEEDS TO OCCUR AND OUTPUT RESULTS AS $files */

    /* get results where $file LIKE %$keyword%; */
        /*********************************************************************************************************/

    //Show images

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {   
        if ($file!="."&&$file!="..") 
            {
                $extention = explode('.', $file);
                if ($extention[1] != "")
                {       
                    echo "<div class='imgwrapper'>";
                    echo"<a class='fancybox' rel='group'' href='$dir$file' return false' title='$filename'>";
                    echo "<img src='timthumb.php?src=$dir$file&h=$height&w=$width' alt='$extention[0]' width='$width' height='$height'/>";
                    echo"</a><br/>";
                    $file_name = current(explode('.', $file));
                    echo substr($file_name,0,21);
                    echo "</div>";
                }   
            }
    }
}

else { // starts the split from keyword or no keyword
//***********************************************************************//

// sort folder names alphabetically, ignore case
natcasesort($files); 

//Show the folders
foreach ($files as $file){  
    if ($file!="."&&$file!="..") 
    {
        sort($files); //Sorts the array (file names) alphabetically -- not the directory/folder names
        $extention = explode('.', $file);
        if ($extention[1] == "")    
        {       
            echo "<div class='imgwrapper'>";
            echo "<a href='?gallery=$gallery/$file'>";
            echo "<img src='images/folder.jpg' border='0'>";
            echo "<div class='folder'>";
            echo current(explode('.', $file));
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<?
//Show images
foreach ($files as $file){   
    if ($file!="."&&$file!="..")
    {
        $extention = explode('.', $file);
        if ($extention[1] != "")
        {       
            echo "<div class='imgwrapper'>";
            echo"<a class='fancybox' rel='group'' href='$dir$file' return false' title='$filename'>";
            echo "<img src='timthumb.php?src=$dir$file&h=$height&w=$width' alt='$extention[0]' width='$width' height='$height'/>";
            echo"</a><br/>";
            echo "<div class='title'>";
            $file_name = current(explode('.', $file));
            echo substr($file_name,0,125);
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}   

}


?>
```

I have the area commented out where I believe the search string would be executed, as the display code is already there. I've tried a few things that didn't work, so didn't bother listing any of it.

Any ideas if I'm going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved from some outside help.

```
if ($file!="."&&$file!="..") 
{
    sort($files); //Sorts the array (file names) alphabetically -- not the directory/folder names
    $extention = explode('.', $file);
    if ($extention[1] == "")   
    {       
        $dir = "pics/";
        $dir = $dir.$file."/";
        $dirhandler = opendir($dir);

        // read all the files from directory
        $nofiles=0;
        $files2=array();
        while ($file2 = readdir($dirhandler)) {
            if ($file2 != '.' && $file2 != '..')
                {
                    $nofiles++;
                    $files2[$nofiles]=$file2;                
                }   
            }
        closedir($dirhandler);
        sort($files2); //Sorts the array (file names) alphabetically -- not the directory/folder names

        //Show images
        foreach ($files2 as $file2){   
            if ($file2!="."&&$file2!="..")
            {
                $extention = explode('.', $file2);
                if ($extention[1] != "" && stripos($file2,$keyword)!==false)
                {       
                    echo "<div class='imgwrapper'>";
                    echo"<a class='fancybox' rel='group'' href='$dir$file2' return false' title='$filename'>";
                    echo "<img src='timthumb.php?src=$dir$file2&h=$height&w=$width' alt='$extention[0]' width='$width' height='$height'/>";
                    echo"</a><br/>";
                    echo "<div class='title'>";
                    $file2_name = current(explode('.', $file2));
                    echo substr($file2_name,0,125);
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }
        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($extention[1] != "")    
{
    if(stripos($file, $keyword) !== false)
    {...
    }
}
```

See ([stripos() manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php))

Comment: Are you suggesting that goes where my commented text is and everything where {...} is to leave as-is, and then place the last bracket right before the "else" command that follows it?

Comment: This is supposed to replace the `if ($extention[1] != "") {` line, you have to place the closing `}` accordingly to avoid syntax errors.

Comment: I inserted it and it didn't do anything. After a search, it finds nothing, so nothing is displayed (and yes, i made sure to use a search term that is in an existing image).

Comment: What does a `var_dump($file);var_dump($keyword);` right before the new `if` give you?

Comment: When I enter a keyword ("boy"), I get: bool(false) string(3) "boy"

Comment: Apparently neither `$file` nor `$keyword` store the expected values. If they did, my code should work. EDIT: Ok, then we have a problem with the `$files` array. What does `var_dump($files)` before the `foreach($files as $file)` loop output?

Comment: $keyword is storing the right value...$file doesn't store a value because there is no query to tell it what to look for. That's the problem I'm having. The code, on its own, works correctly (when no keyword is entered). I just don't know how to structure the search query to look through the $dir for files with the keyword in it. That's what's missing in my commented out area.

Comment: Saw your edit on your comment...I added the var_dump and got this:

    array(5) { [1]=> string(13) "Company Logos" [2]=> string(12) "Stock Photos" [3]=> string(14) "Music Stingers" [4]=> string(6) "People" [5]=> string(13) "System Images" }


Those are the different folder directories that are showing.

Comment: Seems that `$files` doesn't contain what you believed it to contain, does it? I guess you forgot to specify the exact gallery directory, which is why `$files` contains folder names instead of image names.

Comment: That's my problem. I don't know how to write a query to search through the entire directory (and subdirectories) for file names containing the $keyword.

Comment: Yes, I imagine that would help if I knew how to apply it. :D  

I'll have to look more through that, but I'm green enough with PHP that I'm not likely to figure it out on my own. That's why I'm here. :)  But thanks for the help. I'll peruse that when I have a bit more time to focus on it.

Comment: While that function seems to be what I'm looking for, generally speaking, it's way over my novice head and a few tries to implement some code shows that I have no clue how to correctly implement it. So if anyone still has a suggestion, I'm all ears...